# How to put validation on list of String coming from request in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-validator, jakarta-validation

I am creating Spring boot APIs and one of the API consumening data below:

```
class DataRequest{

    @Size(min=1, max=10)
    private String dataTitle;

    private List<String> emails;

}
```

How can we validate List like all strings must be valid emails or matching with some pattern by utilizing a validation framework in Spring controller using `@Valid` annotation?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that directly. Is it an option to have a `List<Email>` and using `@Size` in the `Email` bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bean validation allows you to put the validating annotation inside the container type such as `List`. They refer this as the [container element constraint validation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/8.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#container-element-constraints).

So you can do something likes :

```java
class DataRequest{

    @Size(min=1, max=10)
    private String dataTitle;

    private List<@Email String> emails;

}
```

or

```java
class DataRequest{

    @Size(min=1, max=10)
    private String dataTitle;

    private List<@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z\\d]*") String> emails;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Multiple Validators to validate the objects in a List (using Thymeleaf)

`FormBean.java`

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RecipeForm {

    @NotBlank(message = "{error.general.not-blank}")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "{error.recipe.name.min}")
    @Size(min = 32, message = "{error.recipe.name.max}")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "{error.general.not-blank}")
    private String image;

    @NotNull(message = "{error.general.not-null}")
    @Min(value = 1, message = "{error.recipe.category}")
    @Max(value = 3, message = "{error.recipe.category}")
    private Long categoryId;

    @NotNull(message = "{error.general.not-null}")
    private List<
            @NotBlank(message = "{error.general.not-blank}")
            @Size(min = 16, message = "{error.recipe.step.min}")
            @Size(max = 256, message = "{error.recipe.step.max}") String> steps = new ArrayList<>(List.of("", "", "", ""));
}
```

`ValidationMessages_en.properties`

```
error.general.not-null = should not be null
error.general.not-blank = is required
error.recipe.step.min = number of characters not correct: at least {min} characters
error.recipe.step.max = number of characters not correct: maximum {max} characters
```

`view.html`

```html
<!--/* @thymesVar id="myForm" type="com.example.homepage.form.MyForm" */-->
<form novalidate th:action="@{/postEndpointUrl}" th:object="${myForm}" method="post">
    <div class="col" th:each="step, stat : *{steps}">
       <div class="form-outline">
          <textarea th:id="|textarea-step-${stat.index}|" class="form-control" rows="3" th:field="*{steps[__${stat.index}__]}" minlength="16" maxlength="256" required></textarea>
          <label th:for="|textarea-step-${stat.index}|" class="form-label" th:text="${stat.index}"></label>
       </div>
       <div class="text-start text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('steps[' + stat.index + ']')}">
          <ul class="ps-0 mb-0 small">
             <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('steps[' + stat.index + ']')}" th:text="${err}"></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact ,if you want to control the size of list ,you may use the @Size on you parameter, some @valid annotation has support List.
But if you want to make some complicated function, i suggest you implement your own validation annotation by the support of @Valid.
Follow i will show you a simple implement：

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

/**
 * @author yujin
 */
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {Show.ShowConstraintValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Show {
    String message() default "{com.annotation.Show.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int[] value();

    class ShowConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Show, Integer> {

        private Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        @Override
        public void initialize(Show constraintAnnotation) {
            int[] value = constraintAnnotation.value();
            for (int i : value) {
                set.add(i);
            }
        }



        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            return set.contains(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The dependency is :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```